# http to https AND //domain.com to www.domain.com AND subdomain.domain.com to subdomain.domain.com through htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm hoping someone can help me, as for years I've always tried different approaches to redirecting and came across an interesting one on a project I'm working on.

I need HTTP to redirect to HTTPS
AND
I need non-www to redirect to www but only if //domain.com without any subdomains
AND
I need subdomain.domain.com to still work so do not redirect the subdomain, i'm using wildcard (*) in apache to handle any subdomain as these will be detected in php with $_SERVER and handled for specific tasks.

This is what I have so far however the non-www (//domain.com) ends up in an endless redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
# add www if not subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
# remove www if subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Apache virtual hosts two different files one for non SSL and one for SSL using lets encrypt

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.domain.com
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.domain.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.domain.com
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com-0001/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com-0001/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

All your help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however the non-www (//domain.com) ends up in an endless redirect

It is due to your first redirect rule which should be changed to:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# add www and https for main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# remove www if subdomain   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(?!www\.)([^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now the opposite is happening the www.domain.com gets stuck in a redirect loop instead of the //domain.com getting stuck in the redirect loop.

Comment: Can you try my updated answer after clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to setup different rules for SSL in both www and other subdomains. All you need to do is have a rule to enforce HTTPS and another to enforce www in case you're stumbling on the root domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

# Makes sure HTTPS is used
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Adds www if not subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Important to specify the root domain on RewriteCond for the www prepending, or at least use a less generic rule, such as `^[a-z0-9-_]+\.[a-z0-9-_]+$`.

Comment: Your solution did not work for the subdomains nor the https or non root level domain

Comment: It's funny, because I've got it working on my tests: https://gist.github.com/gkawamoto/0a192909f5344003f1f462a63372d9c1
Did you change the example.com to your domain?